# Contact form 7 will not email form due to it thinks its SPAM

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have  a client that has upgraded wordpress to 3.7.1. Contact Form 7 now reports all forms as SPAM.  I have WP-Mail installed and all was working before.  Any ideas on how to fix this.  Does anyone know where in the plugin code the form is getting marked as spam

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Thanks. I used this to amend this.

```
// a) Did not work for me. 
add_filter('wpcf7_spam', '__return_false');
 
// b) There is another filter for the boolean used in the control statement. 
add_filter('wpcf7_skip_spam_check', '__return_true');
```

Comment: Where do you add this?

Comment: @user2924019 You can use the `functions.php` file of your (child) theme. You can find more info on this in the WordPress codex here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained

Comment: Of course thanks. Been a while since I created a theme. It's not possible to set the reCaptcha threshold from here is it? Looks like it's hard coded within the CF7 plugin code.

Comment: @user2924019 > It's not possible to set the reCaptcha threshold from here is it? Looks like it's hard coded within the CF7 plugin code.
 
Not sure. But I can lend a second pair of eyes. Which file and which function / line are you looking at?

Comment: `wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/modules/recaptcha/service.php` line 182: `return apply_filters( 'wpcf7_recaptcha_threshold', 0.50 );`

Answer (score 1):

Though the Contact Form 7 plugin successfully sends millions of emails every day, there are a host of issues that can stop or delay emails on both the sending and receiving ends. It depends entirely on your local Server & WordPress configuration.

You will need to investigate this issue for your particular local configuration. See [Contact Form 7 Email Issues & Problems](https://blog.cf7skins.com/contact-form-7-email-issues/).

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue happens when we use 3rd party service like sparkpost for sending email or something like that. I tried to check code base how cf7 check spam and found  contact-form-7\includes

then submission.php file, check the code near or search with keyword "spam()"

```
elseif ( $this->spam() ) { // Spam!
        $this->status = 'spam';
        $this->response = $contact_form->message( 'spam' );
}
```

I think besides the wordpress core blacklist checking it also check the sender domain name and bla bla and mark any valid form submission as spam. So I made the spam checking commented.

This is not a permanent solution but it will help for now.

Comment: After few hours of searching the internet I found another solution, which helped us to fix this issue, you can add
add_filter('wpcf7_spam', '__return_false'); 
to includes/functions.php , 
kudos to https://seo-zona.ru/contact-form-7-otpravlennye-dannye-opredelyaet-kak-spam-2018-03-28.html

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem this month and I managed to figure it out.
The default *CONFIG -> DISCUSSION* is applying the disallowed words list to the CF7 forms.

Try adding this code snippet to your theme functions.php file:

```
/**
 * CONTACT FORM 7
 * Disable WP Disallowed List for SPAM validation
 */
add_filter( 'wpcf7_submission_has_disallowed_words', '__return_false', 10, 2 );
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use recaptcha make sure reCAPTCHA’s script file is loaded: https://contactform7.com/faq-about-recaptcha-v3/#response-token-is-empty

Answer (score 0):

Just add below line in functions.php

add_filter('wpcf7_spam' function() { return false; });